# Filter that contains a special word

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to put a filter VBA in the column A that delete the line with words "page".
I'm writing the code, but I don't know how to improve it: I would like to choose only the lines contening the word "Page". My code is:

```
 Sub Mon_filtre_Ligne()
 Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Page*"
 Selection.EntireRow.Delete
 Selection.AutoFilter
 End Sub
```

Comment: I think you may want to use AutoFilter not AdvancedFilter with `Criteria1:="=*Page*"`

Comment: Sub filtre()
Dim Lg%, Plg As Range
    Lg = Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Set Plg = Range("a1:a" & Lg)
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*Page*"
    Plg.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub

Comment: @Tragamor thank you, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Marie: You'll be better off [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67419729/edit) instead of adding lost of hard to parse code in comments

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you, I edited !

Comment: Looks like you are missing a quote mark (`"`) on line 6. Is this actually the case in your code, or just a typo here?